# Starting Sonar fails due to JVM

Tags: jvm, sonarqube, startup

When I'm trying to start Sonarqube 5.1.2 directly after restart of my computer, it fails and I get the following message in the log-file. If I'm trying to start Sonarqube manual during the computer is already running, it starts without any problem. So I think the JVM isn't started yet, when I'm trying to start Sonarqube after restart.

```
Launching a JVM...
Startup failed: Timed out waiting for a signal from the JVM.
JVM did not exit on request, terminated
JVM Restarts disabled.  Shutting down.
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

I already changed the wrapper.config, but it didn't help:

```
# Path to JVM executable. By default it must be available in PATH.
# Can be an absolute path, for example:
#wrapper.java.command=/path/to/my/jdk/bin/java
wrapper.java.command=java


#
# DO NOT EDIT THE FOLLOWING SECTIONS
#


#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Java
#********************************************************************
wrapper.java.additional.1=-Djava.awt.headless=true
wrapper.java.mainclass=org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp
wrapper.java.classpath.1=../../lib/jsw/*.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.2=../../lib/*.jar
wrapper.java.library.path.1=./lib
wrapper.app.parameter.1=org.sonar.application.App
wrapper.java.initmemory=3
# Xmx can't be set to a lower value because of compatibility with Java 6
wrapper.java.maxmemory=32

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Logs
#********************************************************************

wrapper.console.format=PM
wrapper.console.loglevel=INFO
wrapper.logfile=../../logs/sonar.log
wrapper.logfile.format=M
wrapper.logfile.loglevel=INFO

# Maximum size that the log file will be allowed to grow to before
#  the log is rolled. Size is specified in bytes.  The default value
#  of 0, disables log rolling.  May abbreviate with the 'k' (kb) or
#  'm' (mb) suffix.  For example: 10m = 10 megabytes.
wrapper.logfile.maxsize=1mb

# Maximum number of rolled log files which will be allowed before old
#  files are deleted.  The default value of 0 implies no limit.
wrapper.logfile.maxfiles=20

# Log Level for sys/event log output.  (See docs for log levels)
wrapper.syslog.loglevel=INFO

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Windows Properties
#********************************************************************
# Title to use when running as a console
wrapper.console.title=SonarQube

# Disallow start of multiple instances of an application at the same time on Windows
wrapper.single_invocation=true

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Windows NT/2000/XP Service Properties
#********************************************************************
# WARNING - Do not modify any of these properties when an application
#  using this configuration file has been installed as a service.
#  Please uninstall the service before modifying this section.  The
#  service can then be reinstalled.

# Name of the service
wrapper.ntservice.name=SonarQube

# Display name of the service
wrapper.ntservice.displayname=SonarQube

# Description of the service
wrapper.ntservice.description=SonarQube

# Service dependencies.  Add dependencies as needed starting from 1
wrapper.ntservice.dependency.1=

# Mode in which the service is installed.  AUTO_START or DEMAND_START
wrapper.ntservice.starttype=AUTO_START

# Allow the service to interact with the desktop.
wrapper.ntservice.interactive=false

#********************************************************************
# Forking Properties
#********************************************************************
wrapper.disable_restarts=TRUE
wrapper.ping.timeout=200
wrapper.shutdown.timeout=3000
wrapper.jvm_exit.timeout=3000
```

sonar.properties:

```
# This file must contain only ISO 8859-1 characters.
# See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.InputStream)
#
# Property values can:
# - reference an environment variable, for example sonar.jdbc.url= ${env:SONAR_JDBC_URL}
# - be encrypted. See http://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/settings-encryption.html

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#Sonar log level
sonar.log.level=TRACE

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# DATABASE
#
# IMPORTANT: the embedded H2 database is used by default. It is recommended for tests but not for
# production use. Supported databases are MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL and Microsoft SQLServer.

# User credentials.
# Permissions to create tables, indices and triggers must be granted to JDBC user.
# The schema must be created first.
#sonar.jdbc.username=sonar
#sonar.jdbc.password=sonar

#----- Embedded Database (default)
# It does not accept connections from remote hosts, so the
# server and the analyzers must be executed on the same host.
#sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/sonar

# H2 embedded database server listening port, defaults to 9092
#sonar.embeddedDatabase.port=9092


#----- MySQL 5.x
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance


#----- Oracle 10g/11g
# - Only thin client is supported
# - Only versions 11.2.* of Oracle JDBC driver are supported, even if connecting to lower Oracle versions.
# - The JDBC driver must be copied into the directory extensions/jdbc-driver/oracle/
# - If you need to set the schema, please refer to http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-5000
#sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost/XE


#----- PostgreSQL 8.x/9.x
# If you don't use the schema named "public", please refer to http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-5000
#sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sonar


#----- Microsoft SQLServer 2005/2008
# Only the distributed jTDS driver is supported.
#sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost/sonar;SelectMethod=Cursor


#----- Connection pool settings
# The maximum number of active connections that can be allocated
# at the same time, or negative for no limit.
#sonar.jdbc.maxActive=50

# The maximum number of connections that can remain idle in the
# pool, without extra ones being released, or negative for no limit.
#sonar.jdbc.maxIdle=5

# The minimum number of connections that can remain idle in the pool,
# without extra ones being created, or zero to create none.
#sonar.jdbc.minIdle=2

# The maximum number of milliseconds that the pool will wait (when there
# are no available connections) for a connection to be returned before
# throwing an exception, or <= 0 to wait indefinitely.
#sonar.jdbc.maxWait=5000

#sonar.jdbc.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=600000
#sonar.jdbc.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=30000



#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# WEB SERVER

# Web server is executed in a dedicated Java process. By default heap size is 768Mb.
# Use the following property to customize JVM options.
#    Recommendations:
#
#    The HotSpot Server VM is recommended. The property -server should be added if server mode
#    is not enabled by default on your environment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/server-class.html
#
#    Set min and max memory (respectively -Xms and -Xmx) to the same value to prevent heap
#    from resizing at runtime.
#
#sonar.web.javaOpts=-Xmx768m -XX:MaxPermSize=160m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

sonar.web.javaOpts=-Xmx1536m -XX:MaxPermSize=160m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -server -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=false

# Same as previous property, but allows to not repeat all other settings like -Xmx
#sonar.web.javaAdditionalOpts=

# Binding IP address. For servers with more than one IP address, this property specifies which
# address will be used for listening on the specified ports.
# By default, ports will be used on all IP addresses associated with the server.
sonar.web.host=

# Web context. When set, it must start with forward slash (for example /sonarqube).
# The default value is root context (empty value).
#sonar.web.context=

# TCP port for incoming HTTP connections. Disabled when value is -1.
sonar.web.port=9000

# TCP port for incoming HTTPS connections. Disabled when value is -1 (default).
#sonar.web.https.port=-1

# HTTPS - the alias used to for the server certificate in the keystore.
# If not specified the first key read in the keystore is used.
#sonar.web.https.keyAlias=

# HTTPS - the password used to access the server certificate from the
# specified keystore file. The default value is "changeit".
#sonar.web.https.keyPass=changeit

# HTTPS - the pathname of the keystore file where is stored the server certificate.
# By default, the pathname is the file ".keystore" in the user home.
# If keystoreType doesn't need a file use empty value.
#sonar.web.https.keystoreFile=

# HTTPS - the password used to access the specified keystore file. The default
# value is the value of sonar.web.https.keyPass.
#sonar.web.https.keystorePass=

# HTTPS - the type of keystore file to be used for the server certificate.
# The default value is JKS (Java KeyStore).
#sonar.web.https.keystoreType=JKS

# HTTPS - the name of the keystore provider to be used for the server certificate.
# If not specified, the list of registered providers is traversed in preference order
# and the first provider that supports the keystore type is used (see sonar.web.https.keystoreType).
#sonar.web.https.keystoreProvider=

# HTTPS - the pathname of the truststore file which contains trusted certificate authorities.
# By default, this would be the cacerts file in your JRE.
# If truststoreFile doesn't need a file use empty value.
#sonar.web.https.truststoreFile=

# HTTPS - the password used to access the specified truststore file. 
#sonar.web.https.truststorePass=

# HTTPS - the type of truststore file to be used.
# The default value is JKS (Java KeyStore).
#sonar.web.https.truststoreType=JKS

# HTTPS - the name of the truststore provider to be used for the server certificate.
# If not specified, the list of registered providers is traversed in preference order
# and the first provider that supports the truststore type is used (see sonar.web.https.truststoreType).
#sonar.web.https.truststoreProvider=

# HTTPS - whether to enable client certificate authentication.
# The default is false (client certificates disabled).
# Other possible values are 'want' (certificates will be requested, but not required),
# and 'true' (certificates are required).
#sonar.web.https.clientAuth=false

# The maximum number of connections that the server will accept and process at any given time.
# When this number has been reached, the server will not accept any more connections until
# the number of connections falls below this value. The operating system may still accept connections
# based on the sonar.web.connections.acceptCount property. The default value is 50 for each
# enabled connector.
#sonar.web.http.maxThreads=50
#sonar.web.https.maxThreads=50

# The minimum number of threads always kept running. The default value is 5 for each
# enabled connector.
#sonar.web.http.minThreads=5
#sonar.web.https.minThreads=5

# The maximum queue length for incoming connection requests when all possible request processing
# threads are in use. Any requests received when the queue is full will be refused.
# The default value is 25 for each enabled connector.
#sonar.web.http.acceptCount=25
#sonar.web.https.acceptCount=25

# Access logs are generated in the file logs/access.log. This file is rolled over when it's 5Mb.
# An archive of 3 files is kept in the same directory.
# Access logs are enabled by default.
#sonar.web.accessLogs.enable=true

# TCP port for incoming AJP connections. Disabled if value is -1. Disabled by default.
#sonar.ajp.port=-1


#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# ELASTICSEARCH
# Elasticsearch is used to facilitate fast and accurate information retrieval.
# It is executed in a dedicated Java process.

# JVM options of Elasticsearch process
#    Recommendations:
#
#    Use HotSpot Server VM. The property -server should be added if server mode
#    is not enabled by default on your environment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/server-class.html
#
#    Set min and max memory (respectively -Xms and -Xmx) to the same value to prevent heap
#    from resizing at runtime.
#
#sonar.search.javaOpts=-Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true \
#  -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 \
#  -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

# Same as previous property, but allows to not repeat all other settings like -Xmx
#sonar.search.javaAdditionalOpts=

# Elasticsearch port. Default is 9001. Use 0 to get a free port.
# This port must be private and must not be exposed to the Internet.
#sonar.search.port=9001


#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# UPDATE CENTER

# Update Center requires an internet connection to request http://update.sonarsource.org
# It is enabled by default.
sonar.updatecenter.activate=true

# HTTP proxy (default none)
http.proxyHost=
http.proxyPort=

# NT domain name if NTLM proxy is used
#http.auth.ntlm.domain=

# SOCKS proxy (default none)
#socksProxyHost=
#socksProxyPort=

# proxy authentication. The 2 following properties are used for HTTP and SOCKS proxies.
#http.proxyUser=
#http.proxyPassword=


#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# LOGGING

# Level of information displayed in the logs: NONE (default), BASIC (functional information)
# and FULL (functional and technical details)
sonar.log.profilingLevel=FULL

# Path to log files. Can be absolute or relative to installation directory.
# Default is <installation home>/logs
#sonar.path.logs=logs


#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# OTHERS

# Delay in seconds between processing of notification queue. Default is 60 seconds.
#sonar.notifications.delay=60

# Paths to persistent data files (embedded database and search index) and temporary files.
# Can be absolute or relative to installation directory.
# Defaults are respectively <installation home>/data and <installation home>/temp
#sonar.path.data=data
#sonar.path.temp=temp


#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# DEVELOPMENT - only for developers
# The following properties MUST NOT be used in production environments.

# Dev mode allows to reload web sources on changes and to restart server when new versions
# of plugins are deployed.
#sonar.web.dev=false

# Path to webapp sources for hot-reloading of Ruby on Rails, JS and CSS (only core,
# plugins not supported).
#sonar.web.dev.sources=/path/to/server/sonar-web/src/main/webapp

# Uncomment to enable the Elasticsearch HTTP connector, so that ES can be directly requested through
# http://lmenezes.com/elasticsearch-kopf/?location=http://localhost:9010
#sonar.search.httpPort=9010


#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# LDAP configuration
# General Configuration
sonar.security.realm=LDAP
sonar.security.savePassword=true
sonar.authenticator.createUsers=true
sonar.security.updateUserAttributes=true
sonar.authenticator.downcase=true
sonar.security.localUsers=

# List the different servers
ldap.servers=ww007
#,in002
# Configure 
ldap.ww007.url=
ldap.ww007.authentication=simple
ldap.ww007.bindDn=
ldap.ww007.bindPassword=%qcL!XV&G8R4X_2Bm7wG%U
ldap.ww007.user.baseDn=
ldap.ww007.user.request=(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={login}))
ldap.ww007.group.baseDn=CN=
ldap.ww007.group.request=(&(objectClass=group)(member={dn}))

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#exclusion
sonar.exclusions=**/*.doc,**/*.docx,**/*.ipch
```

Has anybody an suggestion how to fix this issue?

Comment: SonarQube 5.1.2 starts up without a problem for 99.9999% of people. There must something related to your configuration. Provide details about that in your question.

Comment: I found a work around. When a started SonarQube with TaskScheduler after restart, it didn't start due to JVM wasn't started yet. Now I start SonarQube as a delayed Service. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Task Manager `Ctrl + Shift + Esc`
2. Go to details
3. Search for `java.exe` and *Terminate it with End Task* 
   Note: There might be more than one java.exe, make sure you terminate all
4. Start the SonarQube